# Integrating a third party library to Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin

I will begin working on a new cross-platform project. I'm going to use Xamarin (not Xamarin Forms) and will need to integrate AdTapsy's iOS library to the project. I mention AdTapsy here but the question is valid for all the third party libraries I guess.

Here's the integration guide for the mentioned library:
https://app.adtapsy.com/app/integration

And here's the guide for linking native libraries for Xamarin:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/native_interop/

What I need to know is, is it possible to link the library by applying the directions in the guide, is this the general way to link libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a 3rd party native library in a Xamarin project, you need to create a [Binding Project](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/) for it.